# XML deserealizations using Jackson

Tags: java, xml, serialization, jackson, deserialization

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="X-TIKA:embedded_resource_path" content="/1.jpg" />
<meta name="Last-Save-Date" content="2018-01-18T13:55:54Z" />
<meta name="Content-Type" content="image/jpeg" />
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ocr">

some text content, test test, blah blah blah

</div>

<html>

<meta name="date" content="2018-01-18T13:55:54Z" />

<meta name="X-TIKA:embedded_resource_path" content="/1.jpg" />
<meta name="tiff:ImageWidth" content="2048" />
<meta name="Y Resolution" content="1 dot" />
<title></title>

<body />
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

I have this classes  for  serialize this  one of many example of  bad formatted  xml shown above

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Body {

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "p", useWrapping = false)
    private List<String> p;
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "div", useWrapping = false)
    private List<DivContainer> div;

    public List<DivContainer> getDiv() {
        return div;
    }

    public void setP(List<String> p) {
        this.p = p;
    }

    public List<String> getP() {
        return p;
    }

    public String getConcatenatedContent() {
        StringBuilder concatenatedContent = new StringBuilder();
        if (p == null) {
            return null;
        }

        getP().stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).forEach(concatenatedContent::append);
        return concatenatedContent.toString();
    }

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class DivContainer {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "id", isAttribute = true)
    private String id;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "class", isAttribute = true)
    private String clas;

    public String getClas() {
        return clas;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

}
```

when I try to deserialize this xml  I get this exception:

> Tika Parsing Exception for [zipArchive1.zip] -  [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Invalid index 0; current element has only 0 attributes 
>    (through reference chain: com.blahblah.contentextraction.dao.ResolveResponseFromEmbeddedParser["body"])

I want to get content from div class="ocr" , this is a generic classes which extract data from different output of tika parser, but not this output.
 Please help !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 modifications to be able to parse this XML document:

1. A wrapper class is needed to deserialize the `<html></html>` element into e.g. :

   ```
   class XHTML {
       private Body body;

       public Body getBody() {
           return body;
       }
   }
   ```
2. `DivContainer` needs an extra field to get the text content of each `<div></div>`

   ```
   class DivContainer {
       // other fields and getters

       @JacksonXmlText
       private String content;
   }
   ```

So in this case `DivContainer::getClas` would return *"ocr"* and `DivContainer::getContent` would return *"some content ..."*

An extra suggestion would be to define any property that's repeated for every class at Jackson mapper e.g.

instead of putting over every class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
```

you can do once before parsing:

```
mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
```

Comment: Problem was solved using newer version of library, but I did some refactoring using you tips, thanks